# How to insert data in Json Format in Codeigniter

Tags: arrays, json, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have 3 fields in my database and I want to add data by row-wise, please help me to add this data in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$json = json_encode($data);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$response = array('status' => 'OK');

$this->output
        ->set_status_header(200)
        ->set_content_type('application/json', 'utf-8')
        ->set_output(json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES))
    ->_display();
exit;
```